# Setting initial price of token on Uniswap V3 single sided liquidity polygon token

Tags: contract-development, remix, metamask, polygon, uniswapv3

I've been trying to set the initial price of my token for the past two days and I'm still confused. Please go easy on me as this is my first time messing with solidity and smart contracts. I have some experience coding in C++ and Python though.

Anyways, I am using remix to develop my token on the polygon network with uniswap V3, and I'm using the 'addLiquidity' function to add single sided liquidity to the uniswap pool so that the price starts at a certain selected price and liquidity is added as people buy in (at least this is my understanding of what will happen, if I'm wrong please correct me). When I click 'addLiquidity' with sqrtpricex96 = 2081153573722230073869968658, I get the below error.

"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract"

When sqrtpricex96 = 79228162514264337593543950336, it works flawlessly (as expected, because I am working from a template that was setup to use this value). I think there might be something wrong with either the fee (tick spacing) or tick bounds. Below is my code. If anyone has any idea as to what I can do to get this working it would be greatly appreciated. I've looked into converting from sqrtpricex96 to tick and tried replacing the '0' tick values with that value to no avail.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

interface INonfungiblePositionManager {
    struct MintParams {
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
        uint256 amount0Desired;
        uint256 amount1Desired;
        uint256 amount0Min;
        uint256 amount1Min;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
    }
    function mint(MintParams calldata params) external payable returns (
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint128 liquidity,
        uint256 amount0,
        uint256 amount1
    );
    function createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
        address token0,
        address token1,
        uint24 fee,
        uint160 sqrtPriceX96
    ) external payable returns (address pool);
}

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable{
    INonfungiblePositionManager posMan = INonfungiblePositionManager(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88);
    //address constant weth = 0xaa25Aa7a19f9c426E07dee59b12f944f4d9f1DD3; //bnb testnet
    address constant weth = 0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889; // polygon mumbai testnet
    //address constant weth = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270; // Polygon wMatic
    uint supply = (1_000_000_000 * 10 ** decimals());
    uint24 constant fee = 500;
    //uint160 constant sqrtPriceX96 = 79228162514264337593543950336; // 1 matic per token
    uint160 constant sqrtPriceX96 = 2081153573722230073869968658;// 0.00069 matic per token
    int24 minTick;
    int24 maxTick;
    address public pool;
    address token0;
    address token1;
    uint amount0Desired;
    uint amount1Desired;

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MyT") {
        _mint(address(this), supply);
        fixOrdering();
        pool = posMan.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(token0, token1, fee, sqrtPriceX96);
    }

    function addLiquidity() public {
        IERC20(address(this)).approve(address(posMan), supply);
        posMan.mint(INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: token0,
            token1: token1,
            fee: fee,
            tickLower: minTick,
            tickUpper: maxTick,
            amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
            amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp + 1200
        }));
    }

    function fixOrdering() private {
        if (address(this) < weth) {
            token0 = address(this);
            token1 = weth;
            amount0Desired = supply;
            amount1Desired = 0;
            minTick = 0;
            maxTick = 887270;
        } else {
            token0 = weth;
            token1 = address(this);
            amount0Desired = 0;
            amount1Desired = supply;
            minTick = -887270;
            maxTick = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If no one has any idea, that's okay. I will be continuing to look into this problem.

Thanks!